# 403 forbidden error after setting seo url in opencart 1.5.4

Tags: opencart

I am trying to setup **seo url** in **opencart** on my local machine.

I have enabled seo url from admin system setting and set it to "YES"

After that, added following lines in my `.htaccess` file-:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files

Order deny,allow
Deny from all

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /primebrand

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

After this, I had set the seo keyword of my product and category. And restarted the Apache.

But it shows

```
403 forbidden

You don't have permission to access /primebrand/ on this server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You had set

```
RewriteBase /primebrand
```

You are telling the Apache that all the rewrites should start in `/primebrand/` directory - that will mean that You actualy have Your OpenCart installed in `<HTTP_ROOT>/primebrand/` directory. In other words, lets say You have a local root `http://localhost/mysite/` and the OpenCart is installed in `localhost/mysite/primebrand`.

If this is not the case (so Your OpenCart is directly the site `http://localhost/mysite/`), set the `RewriteBase` back to `/`, ending up with

```
RewriteBase /
```

This should be enough.

Comment: Even easier is to just delete the RewriteBase line completely. The majority of the time it's not required and Apache is smart enough to figure out the correct path

Comment: Yes, that's true, but it is required by OpenCart and many other systems when installed in a subfolder - in this case I am always keeping this directive just in case I would have to move the system to a subfolder in the future. Then it is easier to just add the subfolder name instead of writting down the whole directive :-) Stupid reason, I know :-D

Comment: No - that's what I am saying. The vast majority don't require the line whatsoever (even subfolders)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `Deny from all`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is possibly your line "RewriteBase /primebrand". It requires a trailing "/", i.e. "RewriteBase /primebrand/"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I have copied files of an old version of zopimlivechat.
I have update files though message was appearing same after update version installation. Site is working fine again .